# Django primary key in tests

Tags: python, django

Now I writing tests for my first django application and have the problem with primary keys, looks like in tests pk isn't auto incrementing.

I set all data for tests, like this:

```
Work(title="Test title").save()
Work(title="Test title").save()
Work(title="Test title").save()
```

And get rows like this:

```
work = Work.objects.get(pk=1)
work2 = Work.objects.get(pk=2)
work3 = Work.objects.get(pk=3)
```

But primary keys I trying to get doesn't match data I pre created, if for data I also set pk, then everything works, I mean `Work(pk=1, ...)`

I just want to know why it works like this, why I can't use auto incrementing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is kind of dependent on several things with Django. The default test class they have you use will actually run each test in a transaction (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase). This leads to your primary keys continuing to increment between classes.

There is also an argument that relying on the PK in a class can lead to bad assumptions...so you have a few choices

1. Don't rely on primary key value (good practice)
2. Save the primary key after object creation and use that
3. Use a different test case implementation that doesn't do this to the tests. Consider (TransactionTestCase) which truncates between tests instead, and leads to more expected behavior (Although maybe not as fast...but I could never tell the difference really)

Comment: TransactionTestCase produces the same behaviour persisting pks between classes